Getting R to run with VSCode
I'd like to try to use VSCode for R programming but what a hassle so far.  I have VSCode and VSCode extension for R installed.  I have R 4.4.1 installed, etc.  Paths are set as follows:
rterm: ‪C:\Program Files\R\R-4.4.1\bin\x64\Rterm.exe
rpath: ‪C:\Program Files\R\R-4.4.1\bin\x64\R.exe

I keep getting the error "Cannot find R client at C:\Program Files\R\R-4.4.1\bin\x64\Rterm.exe".
What is VSCode looking for?  What else could be wrong?

I surprised that Rterm is being used. I would have imagined that Rterm would be ignored if VSCode were the chosen IDE. I don’t understand what is meant by “the paths are set as …”.

The paths to the R executable and R terminal inside VS Code settings for extensions.

Is there documentation that says VSCode needs a path to rterm?

No, I was just going off other answers here on Stackoverflow.  When I remove the path to rterm, the R terminal works.  Go figure.  Otherwise, R intellisense in VSCode still isn't working for me.  It's not clear to me how much of R is actually working in VSCode.

When I updated my R installation I was given option of choosing an editor that was included with the VSCode package. There was information on the VSCode website.

Ok, how does that help me?

It a nudge to go to the docs for the R specific tools at the VSCode site, work through them step-by-step and state which step is in-clear or causing problems.
